# SQL Server : convert dimensions to "Callout" strings in front end

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Firstly, thanks to you lovely folks at SO for getting me through Theory of Comp and Robotics. My question is for my summer internship working with SQL.

I have a table called `[Material Dimensions]` that contains decimal dimensions, and another called `[Conversions]` which allegedly converts decimal values to imperial units including gauge and fractions, then spits them out into a table called `[Callouts]` so that they look like "0.0590 x 0.5000 (T x W)".

The rub is that the client wants to be able to adjust the values in the `[Conversions]` table on the fly and have them reflected in the `[Callouts]` table. Some of these values collide, so they need to be limited by material properties. I know a few parts, like I need to output these values into a string based on their individual properties. I have consulted the googles, and had no luck. I also consulted the SO, and have apparently not used the right search terms. What terms do I need to research, and is what I'm trying to deliver even possible?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I need to know how they're accessing the `[Callouts]` tables and how they're changing the `[Conversions]` table.

I see a number of solutions without knowing more.

If you're using stored procedures or queries, that you can change, to `UPDATE` and `INSERT` into `[Conversions]`, you could add code to update the `[Callouts]` table after each change.

If they retrieve data from `[Callouts]` table by using a stored procedure or query that you have access to, you could change that query to check the `[Conversions]` table to make sure its using current data.

Your final option is a trigger (yuck). You could create a trigger on `[Conversions]` to update `[Callouts]` whenever data is changed. I don't like this option but it's possible.

Please research all three options and see what is the best. Keep in mind that a trigger will slow down performance on your database, and can cause locking.